# Why is liftA2 added to Applicative as a method?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I came across this [discussion](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2017-January/027582.html) on the Haskell mailing list. From the discussion, there seems to be performance implications with adding liftA2 as a method of Applicative. Can you provide concrete examples why it is necessary to add liftA2 to Applicative methods?

Comment: You can often provide an implementation that is more efficient than the standard `f <$> x <*> y`, so you can make shortcuts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The email is written in 2017. At that time the [**`Applicative`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) looked like:

> ```
> class Functor f => Applicative f where
>     -- | Lift a value.
>     pure :: a -> f a
>
>     -- | Sequential application.
>     (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
>
>     -- | Sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument.
>     (*>) :: f a -> f b -> f b
>     a1 *> a2 = (id <$ a1) <*> a2
>     -- This is essentially the same as liftA2 (const id), but if the
>     -- Functor instance has an optimized (<$), we want to use that instead.
>
>     -- | Sequence actions, discarding the value of the second argument.
>     (<*) :: f a -> f b -> f a
>     (<*) = liftA2 const
> ```

So without the `liftA2` as part of the `Applicative` typeclass. It was [defined as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#liftA2):

> ```
> liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
> liftA2 f a b = fmap f a <*> b
> ```

so one could not make a special implementation in the typeclass. This means that sometimes `liftA2` can be implemented more efficiently, but one can not define that.

For example the `Maybe` functor and `Applicative` are implemented as:

```
instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
    fmap _ Nothing = Nothing

instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = Just
    Just f <*> Just x = Just (f x)
    _ <*> _ = Nothing
```

This thus means that the `liftA2` for a `Maybe` is implemented similar to:

```
liftA2Maybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
liftA2Maybe f x y = apMaybe (fmapMaybe f x) y
    where fmapMaybe f (Just x) = Just (f x)
          fmapMaybe _ Nothing = Nothing
          apMaybe (Just f) (Just x) = Just (f x)
          apMaybe _ _ = Nothing
```

But this is not optimal. It means that `fmapMaybe` will inspect if the parameter is a `Just x`, or `Nothing`, and then return a `Just (f x)` or a `Nothing`. But regardless, `apMaybe` will *again* inspect that, whereas we can already know that in advance. We can make a more efficient implementation with:

```
liftA2Maybe :: (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
liftA2Maybe f (Just x) (Just y) = Just (f x y)
liftA2Maybe _ _ _ = Nothing
```

here we avoid extra unpacking of data constructors. This is not that problematic however. For certain data structures like a [**`ZipList`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) the overhead will be more severe because the number of objects is larger.

On June 23, 2017, a new `base` library was published where the `liftA2` function was added as a method to the [**`Applicative`** type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html).

Comment: Additionally – though I doubt that's really part of the reason – `liftA2` is also closer in spirit to the mathematical definition of a monoidal functor, than `<*>` is. Specifically, you don't need a cartesian closed category for (an uncurried version of) `listA2`, only a monoidal category.